# How to compare strings with logical operators to a list of strings?

Tags: python, logical-operators, string-comparison

I'm looking for a way to compare 2 lists of strings. One list has logical operators in it like `["abc" or "def" and "ghi"]`. I am looking for something simple to compare if `"abc"` or `("def" and "ghi")` are in a list of strings like `["def", "ghi", "jlk"]`. Both lists will be coming from a list or dictionary so they both need to be variables. I would like to do something like the following.

```
a = ["def", "ghi", "jlk"]
b = ["abc" or "def" and "ghi"]    

if b in a:
  print("True")
else:
  print("False")
```

I'm also having a hard time understanding why I can change some strings in my comparison and still get a match. The following returns True

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"]

if "abd" and "def" in a:
    print("True")
```

This returns `False`.

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"]

if "abc" and "dea" in a:
    print("True")
```

Comment: There's some syntax confusion here.  If you have `b = ["abc" or "def" and "ghi"]`, this evaluates to `b = ['abc']`, since the expression `"abc" or "def" and "ghi"`evaluates `"abc"` as a truth value, and since it's true, that becomes the value of the expression.  The `or` and `and` conditions are evaluated up front, and are not part of the list.

Comment: Looks like you want to use set intersection and check if it's nonzero?

Comment: Second, if you evaluate `if "abd" and "def" in a:`, this is equivalent to `if "abd" and ("def" in a):` which is equivalent to `if "def" in a:` since `"abc"` is true.  You probably wanted `if "abc" in a and "def" in a:` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite being valid Python code, what you've written is semantically very far away from what you're trying to achieve. This is due to some incorrect assumptions about how the language behaves, or can be made to behave.

First of all, your "list of logical operators" looks and behaves nothing like what you're expecting. This:

```
["abc" or "def" and "ghi"]
```

Is a list literal, which will evaluate to a list containing a single string item thanks to short-circuit evaluation:

```
["abc"]
```

The expression `"abc" or "def" and "ghi"` will evaluate down to a single object, in this case `"abc"`. Non-empty strings are considered "truthy", and the binary `or` operator only needs one of its operands to be true/truthy in order for the whole expression to evaluate as true/truthy.

Second, this:

```
if "abd" and "def" in a:
```

Must be parsed as:

```
if ("abd") and ("def" in a):
```

Again, when evaluated as a distinct boolean-expression, the string `"abd"` is non-empty, and therefore truthy. This is similar to saying:

```
if True and "def" in a:
```

or simply:

```
if "def" in a:
```

There are different ways to solve the issue, but perhaps the simplest solution you're looking for is:

```
if ("abc" in a) or ("def" in a and "ghi" in a):
```

Just because the code you've written reads like an English sentence to you, doesn't mean that this is how Python will interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check for inclusion in list1 of all elements of list2, you need to use a loop through list 2, to check for every element. Depending on the result you want, this can be a list of elements of list2 not in list 1, their count, or a truth array with True or False for each list2 element

Other solution:

ONLY IF YOU DONT HAVE DUPLICATES IN EACH OF THE LISTS: You can turn the lists into a set, this is a special array that only has unique values and that can be used to perform special operations such as
set(list1) - set(list2) = all elements that are in list1 but not in list2.If you want the unique list of elements only in list1 +  the ones only in list2 you need to use the .symmetric_difference method of sets.
set1.symmetric_difference(set2)
or
set1 ^ set2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of lists (simply convert via `set(a)`) and then perform the checks via set operations:

```
s = set(a)
if "abc" in s or {"def", "ghi"} <= s:
    ...
```

The above is true if either `"abc"` is part of the set or both `"def"` and `"ghi"` (here `<=` means subset).

So in order to check whether *all* elements from some collection `b` are contained within `a` (or respectively `s = set(a)`), you can use `s.issuperset(b)`.

Answer (score -1):

the second code returns true since both the string values are present in the list a, and third code returns false since the string "abc" is in the list a and "dea" is not in the list. And i think you can't use the logical operator as a value in the list for comparision